# Auto Generated - CREATE Table Script in SQL 2008 throws error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I scripted the tables in my dev database using SQL 2008 - generate scripts option (Datbase->right click->Tasks->Generate Scripts) and ran it on the staging database, but the script throws the below error for each table

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '('. Msg 319,
>   Level 15, State 1, Line 15 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'with'. If
>   this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or
>   a change tracking context clause, the
>   previous statement must be terminated
>   with a semicolon.

Below is the script for one of my table

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
    [EmailID] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [ContactForOffers] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CustomerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes thats correct, I changed the CREATE to ALTER as the tables already existed. But have changed syntax for ALTER Table. Now works. Thanks guys

Comment: If @gbn's answer was correct, you should 'accept' it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you gave is 100% correct if it was a [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

As an [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), it's completely wrong: this is why you get the error...

The script has been changed since generation: SSMS does not give me "script as ALTER" option

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to script a create, and then run it in a new database, wouldn't you want the 'CREATE' instead of ALTER? I also do not have a script as 'alter' option in SSMS, so as gbn says, it must have been changed.

Edit: As a side note - do you really want field lengths of 500 for first and last name? Seems excessive.